# How would I write this jQuery in coffeescript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

Just trying to learn and confused on how to do the following. Thanks!

```
$.each($(".nested-fields"), function(intIndex) {$(this).find(".set").html(intIndex+1);;} );
```

Thank you again.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The original javascript could (or should) be written like this:

```
$('.nested-fields').each(function(i){
  $(this).find('.set').html(i+1)
})
```

so

```
$('.nested-fields').each (i) ->
  $(this).find('.set').html i+1
```

a more readable version could look like this:

```
fields = $('.nested-fields')

for field, i in fields
  set = $(field).find('.set')
  set.html i+1
```

or

```
$(field).find('.set').html i+1 for field in fields
```

Comment: nice catch for $().each :) (`.html i+1 for field in fields` is not *that* more readable ;) I would do `.html(i+1)` at least)

Comment: i like the last one, but I'd go all the say and make it `...for field in $('.nested-fields')`. And I agree with @arnaud that `.html(i+1)` is easier to read.

Answer (score 3):

```
for field, i in $(".nested-fields")
    $(field).find('.set').html(i+1)
```

(This iterates over the array with a for (;;) loop.)

Or if you want to use $.each:

```
$.each $(".nested-fields"), (i) ->
    $(this).find('.set').html(i+1)
```

BTW the title is a little incorrect; should be *how to write this Javascript in Coffeescript* ;)

Answer (score 0):

Personally I like the `for .. in ..` of coffeescrip but I was boring using the following structure to have the iterator as JQuery object :

```
for td in $('td.my_class')
    $td = $(td)
    ..
```

So I defined a items function available to each JQuery object:

```
$.fn.items = -> $.map(this, $)
```

Now the navigation with coffeescript is simpler :

```
for $td in $('td.my_class').items()
    $td <-- is a JQuery object
```